# How to insert a script reference into a HTML file using windows .BAT file

Tags: html, batch-file

How to insert a script reference into a HTML file using windows .BAT file

I have tried the below code

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  for /f "eol= delims=" %%v in (%%f) do (
    if "%%v"==">Line-X" (
      echo %%v>> %%f2
      echo ^>Line-Z
    )
  )
)
```

My html file code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
--
---
--
</body>
</html>
```

Need output file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="*.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
--
---
--
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't a code request service, you're supposed to provide the code you need help with!

Here's an idea to get you started, it simply replaces the everything up to and including `</head>`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /INC:"</Head>" *.html 2^>Nul'
) Do (( Echo ^<html^>
        Echo ^<head^>
        Echo ^<script src="*.js"^>^</script^>
        Echo ^</head^>
        More +%%B "%%A")>%%A.mod)
```

*Your modified files will have the extension `.mod` so you can check them out*

**Edit**

This example, doesn't close the `<head>` tag!

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /INC:"<Head>" *.html 2^>Nul'
) Do (( Echo ^<!DOCTYPE html^>
        Echo ^<html lang="en"^>
        Echo   ^<head^>
        Echo     ^<script src="*.js"^>^</script^>
        More +%%B "%%A")>%%A.mod)
```

Comment: @MK, I have no interest in that type of comment, either fully explain why it isn't working and what is happening or wait for someone else to respond. The code above, exactly as written, with the example file you've shown in your question, is perfectly good. If you have changed anything at all in your example content or in my script and you don't show me what it is I cannot, and will not, help you further.

Comment: My html code       - My body content length(1000 lines) every time i don't have write code. And inside head   tag reference (20 lines). So all lines don't write.   <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
--
---
-- more than 1000 lines
</body>
</html>

Comment: @MK, my code is working perfectly then, you're just not using your own example with it! My answer specifically said, **an idea to get you started**, that's all it is, and idea; it isn't a robust script you can use on every possible html file you've ever coded. What it does, is show you how you can find lines containing a specific string, assign that line to its line number, and output certain characters using escaping. Your question specifically asked **How to insert a script reference into a HTML file**, and provided input content and output content, my answer shows you one way of doing that!

Comment: @MK, I have added an **Edit** section to my answer showing you how simple it was to not have closed the `<head>` tag. Try the code again, and see the change in the `*.mod` files!

Comment: Thanks @Compo . I will try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169719/discussion-between-m-k-and-compo).

Comment: How to assign the linesCount in varaibel. I have tried this                  (SET totallines= default.htm | FIND "" /v /c) is not worked

Comment: @MK, counting lines formed no part of your question. If you have a specific problem relating to a different issue you should open a new question which outlines the task, includes the code you have written which upon running replicates the problem and explains how the results are undesired.